# How to use Gerund and Noun

Tags: grammar

Are the following three phrases synonymous?

*The battery charging ...*

*Charging the battery ...*

*The battery charge ...*

I will write a academic text. Please help me.

Comment: No. You would use them all in different circumstances.

Comment: Hello Amin. We need to see the context. (It's *an* academic text, by the way.)